# C# Webclient.DownloadString() - how to wait for the page to load before downloading?

Tags: ajax, webclient

I'm using Webclient.DownloadString() to download the complete HTML of some webpages.

Problem is that some of the pages use Ajax to load images etc. and it therefore take 3-4 seconds from when the page looks like it's finished loading till it's actually finished loading everything, including the Ajax images.

So is there a way to make Webclient.DownloadString() wait X seconds before retrieving the HTML?

Thanks,
Louisa

Answer (score 0):

have you tried placing your Webclient.DownloadString() function inside the page_loadComplete function? This will cause your downloadString function to be called only once your page has completely loaded.

The function looks like this

```
void  Page_LoadComplete(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
```

and can also be generated by double clicking the web page in designer view (in visual studio)

Comment: A found a different way to do it after looking closer at the HTML, but thanks anyway.